# Выдаёт ошибку когда пытаюсь получить переменную из другого скрипта c#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Выдаёт ошибку когда пытаюсь получить переменную из другого скрипта c#
Вот ошибка

> UnassignedReferenceException: The variable checkTiem of DoubleTapTime
>   has not been assigned. You probably need to assign the checkTiem
>   variable of the DoubleTapTime script in the inspector.
>   UnityEngine.GameObject.GetComponent[T] () (at
>   <1245d947a91b4a14b7c7e2c7335512b2>:0) DoubleTapTime.OnMouseDown () (at
>   Assets/Scripts/DoubleTapTime.cs:11)
>   UnityEngine.SendMouseEvents:DoSendMouseEvents(Int32)

Вот код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DoubleTapTime : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject checkTime1;

    public void OnMouseDown()
    {
        CheckTime t = checkTime1.GetComponent<CheckTime>();
        if (t.time > 35)
        {
            t.time = 40;
        }
        else {
            t.time += 5;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вам же явно говорит. что переменная не была назначена в инспекторе, читать разучились? (на край, пользуйтесь переводчиком)

Comment: Я вот и не понимаю как это исправить как это произошло

Comment: Что тут можно не понять, добавьте что нужно в инспектор. В переменную эту, добавьте объект и будет вам счастье.

Comment: Нельзя добавить скрипт в геймобжект

Comment: Господи, причем тут скрипт? Вы объект должны добавить в инспектор, в вашу переменную `checkTime1`. На котором собственно весит компонент `CheckTime`.